# Access query DateAdd with between x and y

Tags: datediff, dateadd

Need a little help. I have a query based off a table.

```
SELECT tblLocker.FieldDate, DateAdd("d",180,[FieldDate]) AS ExpireDateLocker, ([ExpireDateLocker])-Date() AS LockerExpire, tblLocker.L6m, tblLocker.LockerNumber, tblLocker.LockerAssignTo
FROM tblLocker
WHERE (((tblLocker.L6m)=True));
```

This works, pulls everything L6m true, FieldDate (7/20/2023), Expiredate (1/16/2024), LockerExpire (6)days till expired.

What I'm trying to do is create a popup message when the LockerExpire is between 1 and 14.

Thank you in advanced

```
SELECT tblLocker.FieldDate, DateAdd("d",180,[FieldDate]) AS ExpireDateLocker, ([ExpireDateLocker])-Date() AS LockerExpire, tblLocker.L6m, tblLocker.LockerNumber, tblLocker.LockerAssignTo
FROM tblLocker
WHERE (((tblLocker.L6m)=True)) OR (((([ExpireDateLocker])-Date()) Between 1 And 14));
 Keeps asking enter ExpireDateLocker
```